# unable to run armitage (java issue maybe) using XForwarding over SSH

Tags: java, ssh, vps, x11-forwarding

I have a headless VPS from godaddy (i know they suck) running Ubuntu 16.04.  I am able to run any other programs I have tried using X forwarding with no issues.  When I attempt to run armitage i get the following error message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f52612e8009, pid=15978, tid=15979
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e" (or dumping to /opt/armitage/core.15978)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/armitage/hs_err_pid15978.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
./run.sh: line 1: 15978 Aborted                 java -classpath bin:lib/\*:. armitage.ArmitageMain $*
```

the log file referred to in the error message can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/XxAXVkwg

thank you in advance to anyone who might be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [OpenJDK bug JDK-8173626](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173626). Quoting the [close comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173626?focusedCommentId=14045310&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14045310) on the bug report:

> As per the submitted report, The issue is coming from OpenJDK 9ea. We would highly recommend you to try running with Oracle's JDK 9ea latest build. Please send us a small test program with 
>   reproducible steps, if you still see the same issue.
>
> Latest JDK 9ea: https://jdk9.java.net/download/